# Mapping 16 English tenses to Japanese tenses

Tags: grammar, tense

I am really confused in digesting Japanese tenses while referring to English tenses in mind. Is there a list mapping each English tense to Japanese one?

Please kindly also provide us with some sentences per tense.

Comment: Not really.  English only has two tenses, and they don't map cleanly into Japanese.

Comment: I'd argue there's three, but yeah. The rest of the variation is aspect. (I actually count a total of 18 different tense/aspect combinations for active verbs, though there's less for stative verbs.)

Comment: perhaps you could list the 16 candidates?

Comment: I'm with @Flaw. What have you got so far. If you don't show some of your own effort then the question will likely be closed for that reason.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder: It is still in progress. Once I have finished updating this question I also hope you show your own effort to answer this question otherwise your comment will likely have no contribution for me.

Comment: I wasn't aiming any intended nastiness at you, only restating a common point of questions being closed. I personally am unsure of the 16 English Tenses you refer to, and as such, without more context, could not answer your question. Also, as with the comment from @snailboat you may find that the tenses will not perfectly tessellate (as is often the cause with Japanese <> English translations). Even if I don't answer, if my comment causes you to reform your question into one that doesn't get closed and gets answered then I doubt that would have been a nil contribution. But I digress...

Comment: We don't intend to be mean. It is that we are unable to attempt to map the elements if we do not have the domain. Your choice of 16 candidates may be different from other analyses of a different number of tenses.

Answer (score 5):

> "Is there a list mapping each English tense to Japanese one?"

There is a simple answer to this question: No. Unrelated languages, like English (or any other Indo-European language) and Japanese do not have corresponding sets of grammar functions, so it is not possible in any meaningful way to map one to the other.

It may sound hard, but you have to learn how different bits of Japanese verb morphology ("endings", in other words) work, and work on hearing enough Japanese that you *understand* it. Whether or not you can immediately give "English replacements" for the bits is largely irrelevant, and if you struggle through trying to pretend that each Japanese structure has a corresponding English structure, you will have a very hard time as you keep bumping into the fact that this is not true.

I hope this helps; that is my intention, but there are many people around with other ideas -- for example that everything is about "translation", which I think is a way to make things even more difficult than they already are.